# MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU and MaxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU not working as documented?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

In an IIS7.5 environment I have configured aspnet.config to set MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU to 1.

I am executing a web service on this instance of IIS for which I have configured to expose the MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU and MaxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU in response to a WebMethod in an ASMX web service which allows me to confirm via the web service that the .NET framework is correctly reading these values in and that they should hence be correctly utilised by IIS by simply having the WebMethod return the values from the HostingEnvironment object.

I also have a WebMethod that simply sleeps the thread for 5 seconds simply called TestMethod.

In theory I believe this setup should ensure that subsequent calls to TestMethod occur in a serial manner due to the fact that only 1 request per CPU is allowed, or, if per CPU actually allows for per core on a quad core system, a maximum of 4 requests are processed in parallel depending on whether it genuinely is per CPU, or whether it's per core.

However, neither of these seem to be the case. For 20 simultaneous requests to this method I would expect to either see a completion time of around 100s (20 requests x 5seconds) or 25s ((20 requests / 4 cores) x 5seconds). Instead I consistently end up with completion times of 10 seconds which implies that 10 requests are being handled in parallel despite the concurrent request limit being set to 1. This remains true when I also set concurrent threads per CPU to 1 also.

Can anyone explain why these settings seem to get ignored, or seem to not work as documented in this case?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this at that time

Comment: @Mohamad I'm afraid not, it just seemed to be flat out broken and I didn't get much help from Microsoft themselves either.

Answer (score -1):

To test this out (and this is a very weird test and NO ONE should ever do anything like this in production) you'll want to set maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU to 1 and then set MaxConcurrentThreadsPerCpu to 0.

The reason is that the ThreadsPerCpu setting is to simulate the old-school IIS limits ("classic" application pool mode).

> There is a corresponding IIS 7.5 change (Windows Server 2008 R2 only)
>   which allows different aspnet.config files to be specified for each
>   application pool (this change has not been ported to IIS 7.0). With
>   this, you can configure each application pool differently.  The
>   maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU setting is the same as the registry key
>   described above, except that the setting in aspnet.config will
>   override the registry key value.  The maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU
>   setting is new, and allows concurrency to be gated by the number of
>   threads, similar to the way it was done in Classic/ISAPI mode.  By
>   default maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU is disabled (has a value of 0), in
>   favor of gating concurrency by the number of requests, primarily
>   because maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU performs better (gating the number
>   of threads is more complicated/costly to implement).  Normally you'll
>   use request gating, but you now have the option of disabling it (set
>   maxConccurrentRequestsPerCPU=0) and enabling
>   maxConccurentThreadsPerCPU instead.  You can also enable both request
>   and thread gating at the same time, and ASP.NET will ensure both
>   requirements are met.  The requestQueueLimit setting is the same as
>   processModel/requestQueueLimit, except that the setting in
>   aspnet.config will override the machine.config setting.  All of this
>   may be a little confusing, but for nearly everyone, my recommendation
>   is that for ASP.NET 2.0 you should use the same settings as the
>   defaults in ASP.NET v4.0; that is, set maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU =
>   "5000" and maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="0".

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx

Comment: Hey, this is not working as well, I am trying to do similar test